# Passing the value to other window from table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm getting values from database and show in the table. And i want to add one button to each row to show details of that row. Now we see just **ThesisID, AuthorID and Title**. I want to open a new window(popup.php) and show more details with this **ThesisID** when i click to button. My problem is i can't get the ThesisID of row from the popup.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    
    <th>ThesisID</th>
    <th>AuthorID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th></th>

</tr>

<?php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
?>
<tr>
    <form action="popup.php" method="post">
        <td><?php echo $row['ThesisID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['AuthorID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </form>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: you should make form data before submit in javascript or make input tags in each <td>

Comment: why not simply put one hidden input ? i.e : `<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="<?php echo $row['ThesisID']; ?>">` ? inside your form . Then when submit button is clicked simply get this `id` value using `$_POST['id'];` at your backend page

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) as follows :

```
<input type="hidden" name="thesisID" value ="<?= $row['ThesisID'] ?>">
```

And then you can simply access the `thesisID` that was passed from the table as,

```
 $thesisID = $_POST['thesisID'];
```

in the popup.php file.

Or else you can pass the id from the URL itself. But without passing the id as plain text it's better to pas it after encrypting.You can use [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function for that.

ex:

```
    <?php
       while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $encodedId = base64_encode($row['ThesisID']);
    ?>
     <tr>
         <form action="popup.php?thesisID=<?= $encodedId ?>" method="post">
```

And then in the popup.php file you can use [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/base64_decode) to decode the encoded id,

```
if(isset($_GET['thesisID'])){ //check if the thesisID is passed

 $encodedThesisID = $_GET['thesisID']; //get the encoded id passed via the url
 $thesisID = base64_decode($encodedThesisID); //this will give the decoded id

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make input tags like this

```
<?php
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <form action="popup.php" method="post">
            <td>
               <input id="ThesisID" name="ThesisID" type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $row['ThesisID']; ?>" style="width:100%; background-color: white; border:none">
            </td>
            <td>
               <input id="AuthorID" name="AuthorID" type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $row['AuthorID']; ?>" style="width:100%; background-color: white; border:none">
            </td>
            <td>
               <input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" style="width:100%; background-color: white; border:none">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit">
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```